Stop Adobe PDF multi-line fields adding scrollbar + set max font size (JavaScript)
I have a fillable PDF form that has multiple multi-line decent sized fields that I would like:

smaller entries to retain font size of 8 as max
larger entries to scale font size down alot before inserting scrollbars
ability for user to be able to come back to field and re-edit without sizing issues

Autosize just looks messy as with differing sizes of fonts, most entries arent long but the odd occasional one is which results in a very inconsistent look.
TLDR: How do I use autosize in PDF fields but limit max font size to 8pt if not much chars/rows are provided by user.
I have got very close using the following method:
Field properties:

Multi-Line
Scroll long text
Autosize

Actions > on Focus > JavaScript:
event.target.textSize=0 //sets to autosize upon re-clicking into cell

Actions > on Blur > JavaScript:
var len = event.target.value.toString().length;

//console.println("LEN " + len);

if (len < 516) { //516 is the exact amount of characters for this field before a scroll bar is needed

    event.target.textSize = 8;
}

else {
    event.target.textSize = 0;

}

Now this works fine if the user doesnt do carriage returns and enters a consistent text block, but all it takes is 5 carraige returns to create a scroll bar.. so I went with an approach to count rows:
Actions > on Blur > JavaScript:
// Get the text field and its value
var textField = event.target;
var text = textField.value;

// Function to count the number of lines
function countLines(text) {
    var lines = text.split("\n").length;
    return lines;
}

// Count the number of lines
var lineCount = countLines(text);

// Check if the line count is within the allowed limit
if (lineCount <= 4) {
    textField.textSize = 8;
    
} else {
    textField.textSize = 0; // Set to auto-size
}


However this is just not performing the else function and always showing as 8pt if rows exceed 4. It looks fine about size 4pt when I focus (mouse click) but soon as I leave field (blur) it jumps back to 8pt.
Sorry if I have done a terrible job of explaining/presenting this, new to forums and JavaScript.
Edit: Example file here that might explain better https://filetransfer.io/data-package/cgAewyHt#link
Cheers

Thanks ive uploaded a PDF with some examples of what is happening and what I would like if its possible :) https://filetransfer.io/data-package/cgAewyHt#link
I did note slightly different behavior with Foxit PDF but all my clients will be using Adobe acrobat.
